# Completeness: Nets vs. Filters

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Given a uniform space $\Omega$.
(See the wikipedia section [Entourage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Entourage_definition)!)

The uniformity induces neighborhoods by:
$$U[z]:=\{x:(x,z)\in U\}:\quad\mathcal{N}_z:=\{U[z]:U\in\mathcal{U}\}$$
Conversely the neighborhoods induce the uniformity.

A filter $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is said to converge to $z\in\Omega$ if one has $\mathcal{N}_z\subseteq\mathcal{F}$
and a filter $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\Omega\times\Omega)$ is said to be cauchy if one has $\mathcal{U}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$.

For the neighborhood filters one has:
$$\mathcal{N}_z\otimes\mathcal{N}_z:=\{N\times N':N,N'\in\mathcal{N}_z\}:\quad\mathcal{U}\subseteq\langle\,\mathcal{N}_z\otimes\mathcal{N}_z\,\rangle$$
Thus convergent filters are cauchy, too.

A net induces a filter base by:
$$\chi:\Lambda\to\Omega:\quad B_\lambda:=\{\chi_\kappa:\kappa\geq\lambda\}:\quad\mathcal{B}_\chi:=\{B_\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda\}$$
The resulting filter is a tail filter.

> Does net-completeness imply filter-completeness?

Comment: I would rather call a filter $\cal F$ on $\cal{P} (\Omega)$ Cauchy if $\cal U$ is contained in the filter generated by $\lbrace F\times F: F\in \cal{F}\rbrace$.

Comment: @Jochen: These are equivalent and as such more or less a matter of taste. I have chosen this definition of Cauchy filters as it happens in the realm of the uniformity so there's a direct analogy to the definition of convergent filters in the realm of the neighborhoods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. See Pete Clark's notes on [Convergence](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/convergence.pdf), which proves the equivalence of nets and filters, and examines the limits of sequential convergence,